# error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I am trying to install FreeSurfer: ftp://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/pub/dist/freesurfer/6.0.0/freesurfer-Linux-centos6_x86_64-stable-pub-v6.0.0.tar.gz

I am following these steps to install FreeSurfer: https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/DownloadAndInstall

When I run following commands:

```
freeview -v \
    bert/mri/T1.mgz \
    bert/mri/wm.mgz \
    bert/mri/brainmask.mgz \
    bert/mri/aseg.mgz:colormap=lut:opacity=0.2 \
    -f \
    bert/surf/lh.white:edgecolor=blue \
    bert/surf/lh.pial:edgecolor=red \
    bert/surf/rh.white:edgecolor=blue \
    bert/surf/rh.pial:edgecolor=red
```

I get this error:

```
freeview.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And when I am trying to install this package:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng12.so.0
```

I am getting this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpng12.0-0:i386
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libpng12.0-0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpng12.0-0'
```

I am totally new to Linux, please help!

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 16.10?

Comment: Yes! I am using Ubuntu 16.10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The software you are trying to run requires version 12 of libpng, which is no longer available in Ubuntu 16.10+. The best thing to do would be to install Ubuntu 16.04, or maybe let the developers of the software know about this problem so they can provide a version compatible with Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 28):

you can either

> install the supplied .deb file available from

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb

```
sudo dpkg -i ./libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

> or compile and install  :

download source code  https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpng12-0

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng_1.2.54.orig.tar.xz

tar xvf  libpng_1.2.54.orig.tar.xz 

cd libpng-1.2.54
./autogen.sh
./configure
make -j8 
sudo make install
```

then update the links with:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

prior to any of this assure your machine has these preliminary packages installed ... baseline for any dev kit

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install libtool autoconf build-essential pkg-config automake tcsh
```

> good news is freesurfer 7 on Ubuntu 20.04 runs fine out of the box

Comment: `user@linux:~$ ./autogen.sh
running libtoolize
libtoolize:   error: One of these is required:
libtoolize:                 gm4 gnum4 m4
libtoolize:   error: Please install GNU M4, or 'export M4=/path/to/gnu/m4'.
ERROR: autogen.sh failed, autogen is incomplete
user@linux:~$ `

Comment: @Sabrina see I added the preliminary commands

Comment: Thanks it worked! - the line `./autogen.sh` raised an error but I kept going and it all worked

Comment: This worked but messed up with my python Qt. Has anyone faced this problem?

Answer (score 8):

My attempt to follow other suggestions (notably Scott Stensland's) on Ubuntu 20.04 failed, with the following output:

```
user@machine:~$ sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package libpng12-0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 69136 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpng12-0:amd64 (1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to install new version of '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0': No such file or directory
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

Per [Linux Uprising](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/05/fix-libpng12-0-missing-in-ubuntu-1804.html), the previous answers do not work on Ubuntu 19/20 because `/lib` is now a symlink to `/usr/lib`, and since the `libpng12-0` installation tries to link from `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0` to `/usr/lib`, the installation will fail.

They offered the following fix, which involves a repacked DEB. With **the standard caveats about trusting code from unofficial sources**, the following will enable libpng12 to run on Ubuntu 20.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libpng12-0
```

Comment: Worked for me on Hirsute (21.04)

Comment: not working for Lubuntu Kinetic :(

Answer (score 7):

Download the shared library from 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download and then run 
sudo dpkg -i

Answer (score 3):

You can find this package at

64b
http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download

32b
https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/libpng12-0/download

Comment: Also works in Ubuntu 18.06.

Comment: These links are no longer supported

Answer (score 3):

I was having problems installing SAS on Ubuntu 18.04.  Some instructions following will only apply to those installing SAS.

The first problem was that the installation would hang on hot fix W83001.  Solution is to move hot fix `W83001pt.zip` out of the `<depot>/hot_fix` directory so it is not installed.

The second problem was that the following package was needed and not installed by default on Ubuntu: `libjpeg.s0.62`.  Installation was done as follows:

```
sudo apt install libjpeg62
```

The third problem was the missing package discussed on this page, `libpng12.so.0`. It was downloaded from [this link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download) and installed as follows:

```
sudo apt install ./libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

After this, I was able to run the SAS software.  Thanks everyone for posting the tips.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install or compile anything. You just need the .so.* files for runtime.

So just grab the libpng12 .deb from the links provided by people above, download the libpng12.deb, uncompress it like an archive (right click and choose extract instead of install with your file application, e.g nautilus if you use the default gnome desktop), go to the 'data' subfolder, in it you will find another folder, inside you will find a lib folder. Grab the two .so files (libpng12.so.0.*) and put them somewhere in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that your application can find them at run time, that's it.

e.g create a folder called libpng in your home and start you application with a script like

```
#!/bin/bash

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/libpng:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

<command to start your application>
```

make the script executable, give it a name, say, my_app, put it in your $PATH like $HOME/bin (create it if it doesn't exist, then logout and login) or /usr/local/bin (this requires sudo) then invoke your application in the terminal by typing my_app or put Exec=my_app in your .desktop file.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to create symbolic links to both PNG and JPEG libraries

```
sudo ln -s -T /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62
sudo ln -s -T /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
```

It will generate some warnings (libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.7 but running with 1.6.28) when running. However, Freeview works ok.

Comment: I know it's not the same problem, but for anyone trying to install **gmic** on gimp (ubuntu 17.10) this trick doesn't work `./gmic_gimp_qt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0: version 'PNG12_0' not found (required by ./gmic_gimp_qt)`. The workaround of @Diogo Alves works though for gmic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libpng12.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 16.04 64bit, and the following worked for me.

64bit

```
sudo apt-get install libpng12-0
```

32bit

```
sudo apt-get install libpng12-0:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

This fix also works for [CANView Log Viewer](https://www.yachtd.com/products/can_view.html), used by Yacht Devices for configuring their NMEA 2000 marine devices.

I don't want to turn this thread into an inventory of all the legacy apps using this library, but Yacht Devices hasn't updated their distribution, and I haven't found their sources (there are many apps with this name).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using snap, try this below command:

```
sudo ln -s -T /snap/core/16091/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Often time researchers use older versions of FreeSurfer (and similar tools like AFNI which rely on since deprecated packages, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1187070/999108) for a related issue with `libXp.so.6`).

To solve on **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**, there is a newer default version which you should use, namely `libpng16.so.x`:

```bash
# to install
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev

# confirm installation directory
sudo dpkg -S libpng | grep libpng16.so
```

- You can spoof the older version name by symbolic linking to whatever deprecated old version you need. It's not guaranteed your old software will work with the newer binaries but generally speaking should suffice. For example:

```bash
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libpng16.so.16 libpng12.so.0
```