# libXp.so.6 missing for ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

```
mc@mc:~$ sudo apt-get install libXp.so.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libXp.so.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libXp.so.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libXp.so.6'
mc@mc:~$
```

and there is no package related to libxp6 for ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Maybe use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~zeehio/+archive/ubuntu/libxp), but it's only available for 16.04

Comment: What do you need it for (by the way, the package name won't be in that form - that file would be provided by the package `libxp6`)? Maybe we can help you find a workaround for your problem

Comment: 1) i wanna run a gui based application in ubuntu17.04. when i run it is requesting for libxp6.

Comment: i also tried with lixp6 in apt repositry , it says no package with that name.

Comment: Get a version of the application compiled for your version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any library that would support this package for Ubuntu 17.04. However there is a temporal solution that works OK for me:

Download libxp6 package from earlier Ubuntu version:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libxp6

Then install it manually using

```
sudo dpkg -i ./libxp6_1.0.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

It seems the package is compatible (enough) with 17.04.

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue when trying to run an old app on Ubuntu 18.04. The workaround that I used was to create a symbolic link named libXp.so.6 pointing to file libXpm.so.4.11.0

Search for the package containing the file pattern libXpm

```
sudo dpkg -S libXpm
libxpm4:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4
libxpm4:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4.11.0
```

Then install the found package - **libxpm4** (if not already installed)

```
sudo apt-get install libxpm4
```

Create the symbolic link:

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

ls -l libXp*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    16 Dec 22  2016 libXpm.so.4 -> libXpm.so.4.11.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72520 Dec 22  2016 libXpm.so.4.11.0

sudo ln -s libXpm.so.4.11.0 libXp.so.6

ls -l libXp*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    16 Dec 22  2016 libXpm.so.4 -> libXpm.so.4.11.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72520 Dec 22  2016 libXpm.so.4.11.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    16 Nov  7 18:25 libXp.so.6 -> libXpm.so.4.11.0
```

If it's still worth for anybody...

Comment: `sudo ln -s libXpm.so.4.11.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6` seems to work on Ubuntu 22.04 

Answer (score 2):

Open the software sources config in a text editor with root permission, for example

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Append this line:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main
```

Then run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libxp6
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else here for newer versions of Ubuntu, the answers above did not work for me, but I was able to install it on 22.04 using the [author's website](https://launchpad.net/%7Ezeehio/+archive/ubuntu/libxp):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zeehio/libxp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libxp6
```

Answer (score 0):

A working solution for installing `libXp.so.6`:

1. First provide multiarch support by

   ```
   wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Proceed to install `libXp.so.6`

   ```
   wget ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxp/libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
   ```

Cheers.