# libmwmclmcr.so cannot locate libXp.so.6 while it is installed

Tags: package-management, dpkg, matlab

I tried to run a compiled matlab code which gave me the following error:

```
.....libmwmclmcr.so Error: libXp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944838/libxp-so-6-missing-for-ubuntu-17-04) that newer versions of ubuntu don't have `libXp.so.6`, so I decided to install it from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/libxtst6/download). 
To check this I ran `locate libXp.so.6` giving me:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXp.so.6.2.0
```

This seemed to look good, however when I run the code again I still have the same error. Similarly when I call `ldd /home/rick/Desktop/tico/tico/v74/bin/glnx86/libmwmclmcr.so`:

```
.....
libICE.so.6 => not found
libSM.so.6 => not found
libXp.so.6 => not found
libXt.so.6 => not found
.....
```

I can't figure out why it is installed but  `libmwmclmcr.so` cannot locate it?

Comment: Is the compiled matlab code 32-bit, or 64-bit?

Comment: @steeldriver Not sure how I can check that? But when I look at the other folders for the compiled code (such as the `V74` folder) I find `glnx86` so I think it is 32-bit

Comment: @steeldriver I guess that may be the problem... But I cannot find a 32 bit version of `libXp.so.6 ` But I installed the `i386` version so that should be 32 hmmm

Comment: If your system is 64-bit, then the correct location for 32-bit multiarch libraries would be `/lib32` rather than `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` I think

Comment: @steeldriver I really don't understand where I'm going wrong I installed it using `sudo apt-get install libxp6:i386` however when I run the code it now says:`libXt.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`. My system architecture is `amd64` though

Comment: What is `tico`? How we can download it to reproduce the problem? What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB notation the `glnx86` means 32-bit.

So you need to install 32-bit libraries from Ubuntu and Debian Jessie repositories

```
sudo apt-get install libice6:i386 libsm6:i386 libxt6:i386

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxp/libxp6_1.0.2-2_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libxp6_1.0.2-2_i386.deb
```

and then retry to launch `tico`.

Comment: Will try this as soon as my linux installation is running again... tried a lot of things which didn't work out well