# installing libpng12.so on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: shared-library

I tried to follow the various instructions for installing `libpng12.so` which eventually led me to do the use the following command after downloading the deb file:

```
sudo gdebi  libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

But, unfortunately, the installation of the deb leads to the errors below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done

PNG library - runtime
 libpng is a library implementing an interface for reading and writing
 PNG (Portable Network Graphics) format files.
 .
 This package contains the runtime library files needed to run software
 using libpng.
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
/usr/bin/gdebi:113: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
  c = findall("[[(](\S+)/\S+[])]", msg)[0].lower()
(Reading database ... 373964 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpng12-0:amd64 (1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to install new version of '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0': No such file or directory
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

Does anyone know why I get these errors? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can I confirm the version of Ubuntu you're using? It's 22.10 rather than 21.10? 

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *kinetic* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 13 October2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 20 October 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/kinetic-kudu-release-schedule/27263  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *kinetic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: package in paste matches *kinetic* & not *impish* - `libc-bin | 2.35-0ubuntu3    | kinetic         | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`  cf. `libc-bin | 2.34-0ubuntu3.2  | impish-updates...`

Comment: I'm sorry to all. I am currently running 22.04. I will modify the title. My sincere apologies.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for R users on Ubuntu 22.04 who get the error described in my  question when trying to load the latticeExtra package during an R session  on Ubuntu 22.04. The
three steps I did were the following. (This was after a lot of googling and many dead ends !!!!! ).

Note that a lot of this answer was obtained using the instructions
from user1335274 at the link below.  I'm just writing them out step by step.

[error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895897/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpng12-so-0)

STEP 1):

I went to ubuntuupdates.org and downloaded libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Then I extracted the files from the deb using ar x libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

This resulted in two files being in my directory called data.tar.xz and control.tar.xz

STEP 2):

I didn't use the control.tar.xz because it was not needed. I obtained the files from data.tar.xz using

tar xvf data.tar.xz.

This downloaded the whole file structure that existed in the xz file. I then copied the two files below into my /usr/local/lib directory. I wasn't sure what the best place was to put them but this seemed reasonable since it wasn't crowded with a lot of other files.

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.54.0

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0

STEP 3):

So, once I had the files above in my usr/local/lib, I then needed to modify my LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my dot bashrc file  so that it included the usr/local/lib directory when paths were looked for.

I did this by putting

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib

inside my dot bashrc file.

Once I did the above, I no longer had a problem when trying to install the latticeExtra package from R when running Ubuntu 22.04. I hope that this helps future R users using Ubuntu 22.04.

NB: Note that often a solution to this kind of problem is to just re-install the respective R package on the new version of Ubuntu. Unfortunately, this was not the case for latticeExtra.

Comment: So I have done what you describe, but now I ended up with
error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Comment: Vitas: I'm sorry but I don't know that means. hopefully someone else does. I have a bash script that updates to the latest R seamlessly, atleast so far. I've been using it I think for the past 3 or 4 R updates. If you want it, email me at myname2 at  gmail and I'll send it to you and explain how to run it. I can't guarantee that it will get around your current problem but  it might be worth an attempt if no one here explains your current error. There are a lot of really knowledgeable on this list so I have a feeling you'll get a useful response.

Comment: I ran into this problem and ended up installing the prebuilt `.deb` binaries for these packages from `cran`.

Comment: I have downloaded the right 32bit version from ubuntuupdates.org and got past that error. Unfortunately then there was a bunch of other various library errors and I fixeed them by installing :i386 versions of it, but finally I ended on libXrandr.so.2 error and that I can't seem to fix